# Creating a blank copy of a SQL Server 2012 database on the same Instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to determine the best way of creating a blank copy of a SQL Server 2012 database, renaming it & placing it on the same server instance. I could restore/rename a backup copy, and then delete all the data, but there are quite a few tables/views, stored procedures, triggers, etc.

Are there any drawbacks with the "generate scripts for database objects" wizard? Just trying to figure out the most efficient way to create a blank copy & would appreciate anyone's experience/wisdom on the topic.

I am running a SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition. We have a database that our colleagues like, so we are planning to create a copy & populate with their data instead of our data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Object Explorer ,Right Click the database you want to create a blank copy of.

Right Click --> Tasks --> Generate Scripts

Select the entire Database, you also have the option to select specific objects, In advance option select **schema only**.

[image]

I would prefer this method over any other, as Restoring a Copy of database and then deleting data means doing a lot of work which was never required to begin with. Backing up data that was never required, restoring unwanted data and then finally making sql server to delete it, a lot of unnecessary work.

Another reason why scripts are better over other options, These scripts will use fresh pages to write all of this data. Imagine you having to write something on a brand new note book as compare to a note book where you had to erase first and then use it to write data on it.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for pointing out that I can select "Schema only" in the advanced scripting options.  Also the notebook analogy was helpful.  I'll try this on Tuesday & report back.

Comment: I was able to successfully create a blank copy of our database using the method you suggested.  I just changed the name of the database, then went through the script to see if other databases were called.  The only hiccup was that I hadn't set "Script Triggers" to True in Advanced Options, so I had to go back & re-script those tables that had triggers that we wanted to copy over.  Thanks!